# Output from sort does not appear to be sorted

Tags: bash, sorting

I have the following text file (sort_test.txt):

```
PGA_scaffold1__77
PGA_scaffold2__36
PGA_scaffold3__111
PGA_scaffold4__129
PGA_scaffold5__109
PGA_scaffold6__104
PGA_scaffold7__69
PGA_scaffold8__63
PGA_scaffold9__45
PGA_scaffold10__49
PGA_scaffold11__79
PGA_scaffold12__71
PGA_scaffold13__52
PGA_scaffold14__91
PGA_scaffold15__101
PGA_scaffold16__33
PGA_scaffold17__51
PGA_scaffold18__69
```

When I try to sort the file with the following code, the sort output seems to be out of order (specifically, lines 9 and 10):

IN: `awk -F"_" '{print $1"_"$2"_"$3"_"$4}' sort_test.txt | sort`

OUT:

```
PGA_scaffold10__49
PGA_scaffold11__79
PGA_scaffold12__71
PGA_scaffold13__52
PGA_scaffold14__91
PGA_scaffold15__101
PGA_scaffold16__33
PGA_scaffold17__51
PGA_scaffold1__77
PGA_scaffold18__69
PGA_scaffold2__36
PGA_scaffold3__111
PGA_scaffold4__129
PGA_scaffold5__109
PGA_scaffold6__104
PGA_scaffold7__69
PGA_scaffold8__63
PGA_scaffold9__45
```

Why do lines 9 and 10 seem to be out of order?

Desired output:

```
PGA_scaffold10__49
PGA_scaffold11__79
PGA_scaffold12__71
PGA_scaffold13__52
PGA_scaffold14__91
PGA_scaffold15__101
PGA_scaffold16__33
PGA_scaffold17__51
PGA_scaffold18__69
PGA_scaffold1__77
PGA_scaffold2__36
PGA_scaffold3__111
PGA_scaffold4__129
PGA_scaffold5__109
PGA_scaffold6__104
PGA_scaffold7__69
PGA_scaffold8__63
PGA_scaffold9__45
```

If I modify the code to only print the first three fields, the sorting does what I expect:

IN: `awk -F"_" '{print $1"_"$2"_"$3}' sort_test.txt | sort`

OUT:

```
PGA_scaffold1_
PGA_scaffold10_
PGA_scaffold11_
PGA_scaffold12_
PGA_scaffold13_
PGA_scaffold14_
PGA_scaffold15_
PGA_scaffold16_
PGA_scaffold17_
PGA_scaffold18_
PGA_scaffold2_
PGA_scaffold3_
PGA_scaffold4_
PGA_scaffold5_
PGA_scaffold6_
PGA_scaffold7_
PGA_scaffold8_
PGA_scaffold9_
```

So, it appears that there's something about the fourth field that impacts the sorting, but it's not clear why.

The problem is, I need the initial sorting, but with lines 9 and 10 swapped.

Does anyone have any thoughts on why the sorting is happening like this and how I can modify it so that produces the expected output?

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Do you really expect 9 and 10 swapped? Shouldn't `PGA_scaffold1__77` be at the beginning, like it is in version with only 3 fields?

Comment: FYI, I couldn't reproduce this on MacOS High Sierra, but I reproduced it on Debian Linux.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, it's a question about how the Linux `sort` command works. [unix.se] would be a better place for it.

Comment: @Barmar - I'm trying to match the sorting that was implemented on a companion file. Sorted a GFF file using `bedtools sort` and the file is sorted in the fashion of the "desired output" in my initial post.

Comment: You seem to be inconsistent about what you want. You say that the version with only 3 fields produces the correct sorting, but it has `1_` before `10_`, while your desired output with 4 fields has `1_` after `18_`.

Comment: @Barmar - I've added a "desired output" example, which should help clarify. Also, in regards to the sort that has `1_` before `10_` I used the word "expect", not "correct". That is what I would definitely expect, but it's not what I'm concerned about.

Comment: It has something to do with using a punctuation character as the field separator in the output. Changing it to a letter produces the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much to @Barmar for pointing me to the [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) forum!

I managed to indirectly find the answer to my problem in this post:

[Is gnu coreutils sort broken?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4422/is-gnu-coreutils-sort-broken)

The solution was to change my locale!

My locale looked like this:

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

After running:

`$ export LC_COLLATE=C`

I was able to get my desired sorting output.